# como desinstalo correctamente sql server?

Tags: sql-server

En la universidad nos toco empezar a utilizar el sql server (express si no me equivoco) y al terminar de instalarlo en mi laptop tenia un error que no me dejaba iniciar mi usuario (el típico user:sa password:123456) quiero desinstalarlo para intentarlo de nuevo pero no conozco donde lo puedo hacer y el centro de instalación de la aplicación solo me da opciones para instalar o actualizar, y lo que yo quiero es eliminarlo e iniciar de cero. que puedo hacer?.

gracias de antemano.

Comment: A mí este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFwkkK6TU9o) me ayudó mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Ve a: panel de control -> Programas y características.
Busca "Microsoft SQL Server" seguido de tu versión y entre paréntesis los bit, en mi caso es "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit)", da click en desinstalar y te arrojará la ventana de apoyo para desinstalar la instancia de sql que requieras remover, si solo tienes una pues solo te arrojará esa. La siguiente pantalla es para remover las caracteristicas (features), confirma que quieres desinstalar y comenzará la desinstalación.
Te dejo este [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=Windows10) de apoyo.